# Super post cleaner, could this be category specific?

Tags: posts

I've used this plugin on many sites, and it works fine. It stops duplicate posts from being created, but the site I'm working on now is a pinterest clone, and it won't work with repins. The plugin is no longer supported, is why I'm here asking. Could this be made to work on only one category? I have one category that works as the blog, the rest of the categories are for the pinterest side of the site

```
 function superPostCleaner(){

    global $wpdb;

    $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;



    $wpdb->query("DELETE a.* 

        FROM ".$prefix."posts AS a 

        INNER JOIN (SELECT Greater1.post_title, Titles.ID, Greater1.MinID FROM (SELECT post_title, MIN(ID) AS 'MinID', MAX(ID) AS 'MaxID' FROM ".$prefix."posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' 

        GROUP BY post_title HAVING COUNT(post_title)>1) AS Greater1 

        LEFT JOIN (SELECT post_title, ID FROM ".$prefix."posts) AS Titles 

        ON Greater1.post_title = Titles.post_title WHERE ID > MinID) AS b ON a.ID = b.ID WHERE a.ID = b.ID");

}

add_action('publish_post', 'superPostCleaner');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is flawed. You should never delete posts by issuing SQL directly to the DB. Use WP_Query to find the posts that are duplicates and wp_delete_post to delete them.

Your current method might generate a lot of garbage in the DB.

Side Note: Best way to prevent duplication is not to allow them to be created in the first place.

Comment: It doesn't add anything to the db, as it's never posted to begin with.

Comment: Then why do you try to delete from the DB?